# Can Orbeon generate an HTML document of a form instead of a PDF?

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon provides a button to generate a PDF version of a form. It appears that it is generating an HTML document and then that is being converted to PDF. I am looking for a way to get that HTML document instead of the PDF. Is this possible?

Comment: I replied below. One question would be what to do with all dependencies (JavaScript, CSS, images, etc.). Having just the plain HTML would contain lots of broken links. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. It is correct that Orbeon Forms first generates HTML and then converts that to PDF (with the automatic PDF mode).